# mysql foreign key using primary key

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys

I have two tables,
diary with columns
id primary key
Narrative text
and
master with columns
id primary key
Diaryid  int
EventDate date
Location int

I want to ensure that master(Diaryid) is always a valid diary(id)

Can I use foreign key to achieve this? Bearing in mind that one key is a primary key and the other int.

Any advice would be apprecaited.

Comment: That's fine, mysql will create an index in master if there isn't one.

Comment: Just tried it and get "Query failed: Referencing column 'Diaryid' and referenced column 'id' in foreign key constraint 'master_ibfk
_1' are incompatible"

Comment: I have a primary key referencing an int (not primary key).

Comment: 'Referenced column 'id' in foreign key constraint 'master_ibfk _1' are incompatible" ' - they have to be the same - please add your table definitions.

Comment: The 'diary' table has 'id' as primary key and 'master' has 'Diaryid' as int.

Comment: Jolly good and the datatype of diary.id is?

Comment: diary.id is a primary key

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/224221/discussion-between-bill-lancaster-and-p-salmon).

Answer (score 0):

Yes you cqan achieve this by using a `FOREIGN  KEY`.

Also you should define it as NOT NULL, so that only exiasting diary keys are allowed

```
CREATE TABLE master(Diaryid BIGINT NOT NULL
,  FOREIGN KEY (Diaryid)
        REFERENCES diary(id)
        );
```

You cqan add

```
ON DELETE CASCADE
```

So that the Master row will be deleted also when the diary rows gets removed

Answer (score 0):

Don't know what is different but problem is solved.
CREATE TABLE `diary`(id int AUTO_INCREMENT, Narrative text, PRIMARY KEY(`id`))
CREATE TABLE `master`(`id` int AUTO_INCREMENT, `Diaryid` int,`datemade` date, FOREIGN KEY(`Diaryid`) REFERENCES `diary`(`id`), primary key (id))
So am now adding diary records and can have multiple master records so long as the Diaryid is valid
Thanks